# Cordova - File Transfer not save downloaded file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a little problem with File Transfer plugin. I'm trying to use this plugin for save an image in a folder, the success event is trigged, but when I go in the folder where the file could be saved, it result empty.

```
function downloadAction(link) {
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {

    console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);

    var url = 'http://cordova.apache.org/static/img/cordova_bot.png';
    fs.root.getFile('downloaded-image.png', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        download(fileEntry, url);

    }, fail);

}, fail);}

function download(fileEntry, uri) {

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function (entry) {
        console.log("Successful download...");
        window.alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    null, // or, pass false
    {
        //headers: {
        //    "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        //}
    }
);}

function fail (error)
{
    window.alert(error.message);
}
```

P.s I dont have access problem, my app allow all origin ... I think ...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="------------------" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>-------------</name>
<description>
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Maybe I cant access to that path ? I cant create an entity there ?

[Output of success callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy1zd.png)

Comment: `but when I go in the folder where the file could be saved`. Please put in your post that the file is saved in /data/data/<packagename>files. That is internal private memory. You cannot just go there as you said. What did you use? A file explorer app?

Comment: `fs.root.getFile('downloaded-image.png',`. You use .root. Are there other options? If not then use an absolute path.

Comment: Yes I used an explorer app ... So I cant put my file in this path ? What path i should use ? There is a way to use Download directory ?

Comment: `but when I go in the folder where the file could be saved, it result empty.`. I indicated that you could not go to that folder. But you did not react. Nor did you tell which path you exactly went.

Comment: the path is "file:///data/data/com.yourname.nameapp/files/files/downloaded-image.png" as said the image I posted. I think that you have right and I cant acess there. Anyway thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: I have the same problem, I used 'cordova.file.externalDataDirectory'. It succeeds right away, but when I navigate there (with Android's file explorer), the file is there, but 0 bytes!!